# Converting String to Float is not giving exact value in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, cgfloat

I wrote a sample to **convert string to float** in Objective-C:

```
NSString *sampleFloatString = @"1.3";
float sampleFloatValue = [sampleFloatString floatValue];
```

But when I display `sampleFloatValue`, it shows '1.29999995'. I know it's equal to 1.3, but why is it not exactly '1.3'? Why do we need to format it explicitly? Is there any other way of doing this conversion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its called "Floating point error".  The way that computers represent decimal numbers causes them to not be 100% accurate all the time:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Yeah, It make sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
float sampleFloatValue = (float) sampleFloatString;
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

if you just wants to show these value somewhere than u can do these and it shows 1.3 exact..

```
NSString *sampleFloatString = @"1.3";
float sampleFloatValue = [sampleFloatString floatValue];
NSLog(@"%.1f",sampleFloatValue);
```